# Inequality conntected with Legendre's formula

Tags: number-theory

Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive integers. Prove that $v_2(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2) \leq 2v_2(x)+2$ where $v_2(x) = \min(v_2(a),v_2(b),v_2(c),v_2(d))$ Any ideas how to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** The square of an odd number always has the form $8n+1$ and the square of an even number always has the form $4n$.

> The square of an odd number always has the form $8n+1$ because $$(2m+1)^2=4\underbrace{m(m+1)}_{\text{multiple of }2}+1=8n+1.$$

---

> **Case 1:** When one of $a, b, c, d$ is odd **OR** three of them are odd, $\text{LHS}=0$.
>  
>  **Case 2:** When two of $a, b, c, d$ are odd (WLOG assume $a^2=8p+1, b^2=8q+1, c^2=4r, d^2=4s$), we have 
> $$\text{LHS}=v_2(2(\underbrace{4p+4q+2r+2s+1}_{\text{odd}}))=1.$$
>
>  **Case 3:** When all are odd, by assuming $a^2=8p+1, b^2=8q+1, c^2=8r+1, d^2=8s+1$, we have
> $$\text{LHS}=v_2(4(\underbrace{2p+2q+2r+2s+1}_{\text{odd}}))=2.$$
>
>  When all are even, WLOG we may assume $v_2(a)=v_2(x)$. Then, we can certainly pull out $2v_2(x)=v_2(a^2)$ out of $\rm LHS$ so it becomes the above three cases.

Comment: Could you explain more precisely that case when all of $,a,b,c,d$ are even?

Comment: For example, consider $\{a^2,b^2,c^2,d^2\}=\{(3\cdot 2^2)^2, (2^3)^2, (2^4)^2, (5\cdot 2^5)^2\}$, then we can pull out $(2^2)^2=16$ to form new $\{a'^2,b'^2,c'^2,d'^2\}=\{(3)^2, (2)^2, (2^2)^2, (5\cdot 2^3)^2\}$, which is **Case 1**.